# No visible @interface for 'BinaryFileReader' declares the selector 'initWithLocation:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-io

I am having an this error come up:

`No visible @interface for 'BinaryFileReader' declares the selector 'initWithLocation:'`

for every method called on BinaryFileReader in the method below.

```
+ (Item*)loadItem:(NSString*)filepath {
  Item* newItem = [[Item alloc] init];
  BinaryFileReader* input = [[BinaryFileReader alloc] initWithLocation:filepath];
  [newItem setName:[input readNSString]];
  [newItem setOtherNames:[input readNSMutableArrayOfNSString]];
  [newItem setDescription:[input readNSString]];
  [newItem setXactCode:[input readNSString]];
  [newItem setSymbilityCode:[input readNSString]];
  [newItem setAverageLowPrice:[input readInt]];
  [newItem setAverageHighPrice:[input readInt]];
  [newItem setAverageLifeExpectancy:[input readInt]];
  return newItem;
}
```

Here is my BinaryFileReader.m:

```
#import "BinaryFileReader.h"

@implementation BinaryFileReader

- (id)init {
  self = [super init];
  return self;
}

- (id)initWithLocation:(NSString*)filepath {
  if ((self = [super init])) {
      _file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filepath];
      _fileOffset = 0;
      if (_file == nil)
          NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open file at path:",filepath);
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)close {
  [_file closeFile];
}

- (int)readInt {
  [_file seekToFileOffset:_fileOffset];
  _databuffer = [_file readDataOfLength:4];
  _fileOffset+=4;
  return (*(int*)([_databuffer bytes]));
}
- (NSString*)readNSString {
  int length = [self readInt];
  [_file seekToFileOffset:_fileOffset];
  _databuffer = [_file readDataOfLength:length];
  _fileOffset+=length;
  return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_databuffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

- (NSMutableArray*)readNSMutableArrayOfNSString {
  NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  int arrayLength = [self readInt];
  int length;
  for (int i=0; i<arrayLength; i++) {
      length = [self readInt];
      [_file seekToFileOffset:_fileOffset];
      _databuffer = [_file readDataOfLength:length];
      _fileOffset+=length;
      [array addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:_databuffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  }
  return array;
}

@end
```

And BinaryFileReader.h:

```
@interface BinaryFileReader : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) int fileOffset;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData* databuffer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFileHandle* file;

- (id)init;
- (id)initWithLocation:(NSString*)filepath;
- (void)close;
- (int)readInt;
- (NSString*)readNSString;
- (NSMutableArray*)readNSMutableArrayOfNSString;

@end
```

I don't understand why I am having this issue. Any help to clear this up would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if that is a problem, but why is the return type of your init methods `id`?

Comment: Because it is [the way to implement initialization methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html).

Comment: Forgot to include the BinaryFileReader header in the file triggering the error?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the code you posted. It may be useful to post the whole files.

Comment: I did post everything... did you mean posting the file that + (Item*)loadItem is a part of? Also to debunk the statement "Forgot to include the BinaryFileReader header I do have #import "BinaryFileReader.h"

Comment: I'm with Gerd.. check if all includes are registerd..

Comment: Is there a copy of `BinaryFileReader.h` floating around somewhere?

Comment: I saw that answer on another stack overflow question as well. I have search for one and can find none. I searched with the console list files command and I have it set to show hiddens and still no duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy&pasted the code from your question into a project of mine. Expected result: Everything compiles fine. So it's definitely not your code that is the problem.

Coming back to the idea of a different `BinaryFileReader.h` polluting your #imports: Do you use any third party libraries in your project? If yes, one of those might unexpectedly provide a `BinaryFileReader.h` file.

Try this: Rename `BinaryFileReader.h` to something else, e.g. `Foo.h`. Also change the #import in `BinaryFileReader.m` to use `Foo.h`, but leave the #import in the file where your `loadItem:` method is located so that it still uses `BinaryFileReader.h`. Now compile again. The compiler should now complain that it can't find `BinaryFileReader.h`. If the error is still about the missing selector then you know that somewhere you have an unexpected `BinaryFileReader.h` messing up your project.

Comment: It does indeed complain that BinaryFileReader.h does not exist.

Comment: @Hoodai Then I must admit defeat. The only other advice that I can give is this: Make a copy of your project, rip out everything except the 3 files that are involved. If this super-minimalistic project still has the compiler error you can then upload the mini-project somewhere for us to have a look.

Comment: Ok, so... I fixed it...sorta. What I did was, after renaming it, I changed the #import in Item.m from #import BinaryFileReader.h to #import Foo.h and all the references to Foo... I then ran and complied it fine. Clearly something wrong with the name "BinaryFileReader", right? that's what I thought to but upon changing everything BACK to BinaryFileReader from Foo, it worked fine. SUMMARY - I have no clue what this phantom error was about and it set me behind 1/2 a day's work but @herzbube you did give me the answer that eventually led to the solution so best answer there.

Comment: @Hoodai Very weird indeed. Somehow or other Xcode must have cached an old version of `BinaryFileReader.h`, but how it did this (precompiled header?) is beyond me. Glad to hear you're back on track, now, and thanks for accepting the answer.